# Meteor 1.2 deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, meteor, frameworks

I am trying to implement the MeteorJS application on a CentOS server. And when I run the **mup setup**, I get the following error.
I see a problem with some modules.
The **meteor version is 1.2**, it uses **node v0.10***.
The application is old, it was made in 2017.
[image]

Thank you all.

Comment: This has neither to do with mup nor with the meteor version but is due to failed authentication (misconfigured ssh or wrong credentials).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you perhaps know how this can be fixed? @Jankapunkt

Comment: Can you ssh into your server? You need to use this credentials in your `mup.js` file to make mup able to execute commands on your server.

Comment: That I can access the server. And I put the same parameters (user and passwd) in the mup.js file. And when I run the mup setup, I get the same error.

Comment: If you think you can solve it, we can connect, so I would pay you some compensation for that. Thank you. @Jankapunkt

Comment: Let's continue in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229734/meteor-talk)